# google classroom API Create Topic

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

Im looking for topic attribute in course or courseWork class for grouping courseWork (Task or Question) by Topic like i did for google classroom user interface.

Is it possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been requested and according to this [github forum](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/551), no apparent direct updates have been given. Closest I found was in [this blog](http://alicekeeler.com/2016/08/17/new-features-google-classroom-fall-2017/) where you can add topics when making assignments manually. I don't think it's available through API yet.